# Building omniORB-4.2.5 with vs2019 for win64, but it always report error LINK1104: can't open file "python27.obj"

Tags: omniorb

I did it according to README.win32.txt, the config/config.mk select 'platform = x86_win32_vs_16' and set 'PYTHON = /cygdrive/d/Python27/python' in mk/platforms/x86_win32_vs_16.mk file, I also set cygwin64 to env PATH，but when I run 'make export', it always report error LINK1104: can't open file "python27.obj"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGZcp.png)

Comment: Whether I need to compile Python from source, I can't fined any *.obj file in Python27/ dir

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved!
Only need change src/mk/python.mk file like above:

PYVERSION := $(shell $(PYTHON) -c 'import sys; sys.stdout.write(".".join(sys.version.split()[0].split(".")[:2]))')